# how to pass varialble from controller to directive using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass variable from controller to directive using angularjs.below is my sample code to pass data from controller to directive but in directive i am not getting data.I am writing one function in controller in that controller i am getting data.but i want to pass that data into directive so please suggest me how to this.

Controller.js:

```
$scope.selectNode=function()
        {

            $scope.nodeval="This is sample";

        };
```

Directive.js:

```
iElement.bind('click', function() {
    alert("click: "+nodeval);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: try alert("click: " + scope.nodeval);

Comment: Do a Plunker or Fiddle if you want somebody to give a relevant answer.

Comment: need to shore more details. Nobody can give you direection without seeing how your code currently works. Show html and more of directive